# Optimizing Multiprocessing in Python (Follow Up: using Queues)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is a followup question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972136/optimizing-multiprocessing-in-python). User Will suggested using a queue, I tried to implement that solution below. The solution works just fine with j=1000, however, it hangs as I try to scale to larger numbers. I am stuck here and cannot determine why it hangs. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Also, the code is starting to get ugly as I keep messing with it, I apologize for all the nested functions.

```
def run4(j):
    """
    a multicore approach using queues
    """
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count
    import os

    def bazinga(uncrunched_queue, crunched_queue):
        """
        Pulls the next item off queue, generates its collatz
        length and 
        """
        num = uncrunched_queue.get()
        while num != 'STOP': #Signal that there are no more numbers
            length = len(generateChain(num, []) )
            crunched_queue.put([num , length])
            num = uncrunched_queue.get()

    def consumer(crunched_queue):
        """
        A process to pull data off the queue and evaluate it
        """
        maxChain = 0
        biggest = 0
        while not crunched_queue.empty():
            a, b = crunched_queue.get()
            if b > maxChain:
                biggest = a
                maxChain = b
        print('%d has a chain of length %d' % (biggest, maxChain))

    uncrunched_queue = Queue()
    crunched_queue = Queue()
    numProcs = cpu_count()

    for i in range(1, j): #Load up the queue with our numbers
        uncrunched_queue.put(i)
    for i in range(numProcs): #put sufficient stops at the end of the queue
        uncrunched_queue.put('STOP')

    ps = []
    for i in range(numProcs):
        p = Process(target=bazinga, args=(uncrunched_queue, crunched_queue))
        p.start()
        ps.append(p)

    p = Process(target=consumer, args=(crunched_queue, ))
    p.start()
    ps.append(p)

    for p in ps: p.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're putting `'STOP'` poison pills into your `uncrunched_queue` (as you should), and having your producers shut down accordingly; on the other hand your consumer only checks for emptiness of the crunched queue:

```
while not crunched_queue.empty():
```

(this working *at all* depends on a race condition, btw, which is not good)

When you start throwing non-trivial work units at your `bazinga` producers, they take longer.  If all of them take long enough, your `crunched_queue` dries up, and your consumer dies.  I think you may be misidentifying what's happening - your program doesn't "hang", it just stops outputting stuff because your consumer is dead.

You need to implement a smarter methodology for shutting down your consumer.  Either look for *n* poison pills, where *n* is the number of producers (who accordingly each toss one in the `crunched_queue` when they shut down), or use something like a `Semaphore` that counts up for each live producer and down when one shuts down.

Comment: I added the following to the end of bazinga():
    `crunched_queue.put(['STOP', 'STOP'])`
and I added a counter to consumer to stop after the appropriate number of stops have been received.
This works just fine, however, the script does not appear to be using more than one processor (there is only one Python process in my Activity Manager instead of numProcs+1). This is causing incredibly slow runs when j>10000. The original post where I broke the problem in to chunks split between the processors fine, do you know why this one won't?